# email fetching without css contents

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch emails and echo them in laravel but some emails have some CSS contents in their HTML bodies, which spoils the appearance of my entire page.

I even tried to escape it like `echo e($body);`

But this does not solve the issue.

Comment: {!! $body !!}   saved the entire file in database but fetching it to display again

Comment: can I know what the negative points for

Comment: depending on your code it is simple .. just if(!$body){save_cleandata($data); } and to display echo showData($data); simple or

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507155/php-imap-fetch-body

Comment: previously posted this post u can use the above link for the code

Comment: any one got any idea

Comment: No, not until you follow the guidelines: please post a minimal example of your code (IN TEXT!) recreating the showing the problem.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with IMAP, it is about rendering HTML documents in other HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had to customise emails fetched by me which I must not suppose to do so but any ways I got it working as exact as any mail server.